# coredns doesnt give IP but just name

Tags: kubernetes, nslookup, dig, coredns

By running a dig command for a service in my kubernetes cluster, coredns just gives service name but not the IP. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Needs details or clarity from where you are running command and what you want?. `kubectl get svc -n kube-system` may directly provide the details or IP of coreDNS if exposed any how.

Comment: kubectl exec -ti busybox nslookup myservicename.... this is the command i am using and busybox is the pod i am running in.... it doesn't give IP but just the name

Comment: Attach an output of nslookup is helpful.

Comment: Please update your question with resources requested by users Harsh Manvar and Kun Li. Also please add the result of: `$ kubectl describe service svc-name-you-are-trying-to-query`.

Answer (score 0):

This is related with how **dig** utility and **DNS** work.

Note that when you run:

```
dig <your-service-name>
```

you're asking your **CoreDNS** literally about this particular string and simple service name isn't even a valid domain name. Just take a look at the following example:

```
root@python-client:/# dig my-release-mysql

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u2-Debian <<>> my-release-mysql
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27445
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;my-release-mysql.              IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       86399   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2021012500 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 10.3.240.10#53(10.3.240.10)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 25 16:22:12 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 120
```

As you can see it doesn't even contain `"ANSWER"` section (`ANSWER: 0`) and if you take a closer look at the `"QUESTION"` section:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;my-release-mysql.              IN      A
```

you'll notice that **dig** asks **CoreDNS** for `A` record for `my-release-mysql.`, which, as I already mentioned, isn't even a valid domain name.

Note that **CoreDNS** doesn't keep any records for `my-release-mysql.` so when you ask it about such "domain", it doesn't know anything about it.

If you ask instead for `A` record for a valid **fully quallified domain name (FQDN)**, you'll get the expected response:

```
root@python-client:/# dig my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u2-Debian <<>> my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47573
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN A 10.3.244.87

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.3.240.10#53(10.3.240.10)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 25 15:59:55 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76
```

Again, take a closer look at both `"QUESTION"` and `"ANSWER"` sections:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN A 10.3.244.87
```

As you can see, when we ask **CoreDNS** in `QUESTION SECTION` for an `A` record for `my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local.` which happens to be a **valid FQDN** (unlike `my-release-mysql.`) that this DNS server keeps records for, we get correct response in our `ANSWER SECTION`.

Note that **dig** utility doesn't use entries in your `/etc/resolv.conf` which may look as follows:

```
root@python-client:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.3.240.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

but instead, it queries the DNS server about the raw string `my-release-mysql.`.

Tools like `host` or `nslookup`, unlike **dig**, leverage the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` when doing DNS lookup. So instead of asking **CoreDNS** about raw `my-release-mysql`, `default.svc.cluster.local` suffix is added and such query is sent to **CoreDNS** e.g.:

```
root@python-client:/# host my-release-mysql
my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.3.244.87
```

Note, that although we give `my-release-mysql` as an argument for our `host` command, it matches it with the first entry in the `search` section of our `/etc/resolv.conf` file, which happens to be `default.svc.cluster.local` and queries the DNS server not about `my-release-mysql` but about a fully quallified domain name `my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local` for which it keeps records.

Same thing with `nslookup` tool:

```
root@python-client:/# nslookup my-release-mysql
Server:         10.3.240.10
Address:        10.3.240.10#53

Name:   my-release-mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.3.244.87
```